# Find Duplicate and change their color

Tags: vba, excel

I have some account ids in column D and their issue date in column B, Now I need to find duplicate account ids and change their color from it's date..for recent date yellow and for previous date red..please help..

I have try these..but isn't work!

```
Sub Duplicates()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim cel As Range
i As Long
Dim dateone As Date, datetwo As Date

'Test for duplicates in a single column
'Duplicates will be highlighted in red

Set Rng = Range(Range("D1"), Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

For Each cel In Rng

If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cel.Value) > 1 Then

    dateone = DateValue(cel.Offset(0, -2))
    datetwo = DateValue(cel.Offset(0, -2))

    If dateone < datetwo Then
    cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    Else
    cel.Interior.ColorIndex = 5
    End If


End If
Next cel
i = i + 1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Its almost good. Note that `dateone` always equal `datetwo`. 
You need use one more `loop` to find all duplicate.

> change their color from it's date..for recent date yellow and for previous date red

This is a little more complicated, it worked so well, you have to find the maximum value for each `id` and change color to yellow, after that change all other to red.

One of the many solutions:

```
Sub Duplicates()

Dim Rng As Range
Dim cel As Range, cel2 As Range, i As Long
Dim datemax As Date
'Test for duplicates in a single column 'Duplicates will be highlighted in red

Set Rng = Range(Range("D1"), Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

'change color all id to white
Rng.Interior.Color = vbWhite

For Each cel In Rng

    If WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Rng, cel.Value) > 1 And cel.Interior.Color = vbWhite Then
    datemax = DateValue(cel.Offset(0, -2))

        'find the maximum date
        For Each cel2 In Rng
            If cel2.Value = cel.Value And datemax < DateValue(cel2.Offset(0, -2)) Then
                datemax = DateValue(cel2.Offset(0, -2))
            End If
        Next cel2

        'coloring cells
        For Each cel2 In Rng
            If cel2.Value = cel.Value Then
                If datemax = DateValue(cel2.Offset(0, -2)) Then
                cel2.Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Else
                cel2.Interior.Color = vbRed
                End If
            End If
        Next cel2
    End If
Next cel

End Sub
```

Comment: It's worked success fully, Thanks you very much for your needful help.. :)

Answer (score 0):

You were comparing two identical values every time : `dateone = DateValue(cel.Offset(0, -2))` and `datetwo = DateValue(cel.Offset(0, -2))`

Try this :

```
Sub Duplicates()

Dim LastRow As Integer, _
    i As Integer, _
    k As Integer, _
    DateOne As Date, _
    DateTwo As Date

With ActiveSheet
    LastRow = .Range("D" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)

    For i = 1 To LastRow - 1
        For k = i + 1 To LastRow
            'Test for duplicates in a single column
            If .Cells(i, 4) <> .Cells(k, 4) Then
            Else
                DateOne = DateValue(.Cells(i, 2))
                DateTwo = DateValue(.Cells(k, 2))

                If DateOne < DateTwo Then
                    .Cells(i, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                    .Cells(k, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
                Else
                    .Cells(i, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
                    .Cells(k, 4).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
                End If
            End If
        Next k
    Next i
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It's worked success fully, Thanks you very much for your needful help.. :)

Comment: Glad I could help! Please validate answer (the grey tick under up and down votes) so that your problem is marked as solved! ;)